# calloc allocatin 0 bytes for a struct field

Tags: c, valgrind

Heyo,
I have problem allocating memory for my "database"

i have this struct

```
typedef struct TPrvek {
    struct TPrvek *parent1;
    struct TPrvek *parent2;

    int id;//key

    char *name;//value
} TPrvek;

typedef struct Database {
    int size;
    struct TPrvek **TField;
} DATABASE;
```

and I am initializing like this :

```
void init(DATABASE *db) {
    DATABASE *newDb = (DATABASE *) malloc(sizeof(DATABASE));
    newDb->size = 1000;//initial capacity
    newDb->TField = (TPrvek **) calloc(newDb->size, sizeof(TPrvek *));
    for (int i = 0; i < db->size; i++) {
        newDb->TField[i] = NULL;
    }
    *db = *newDb;
}
```

But when i try to insert smth to it, im writing out of allocated memmory and I don't know how to repair it nor what is even wrong
snipet of insertion:

```
    int addPerson(DATABASE *db,
                  int id,
                  const char *name,
                  int id1,
                  int id2) {
        //some checks to make sure ids are in bounds and field for new person is empty
    
        TPrvek *clovek = (TPrvek *) malloc(sizeof(TPrvek));
        
            clovek->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);
            strcpy(clovek->name, name);
            clovek->id = id;
        
            //clovek->parent1 = (TPrvek *) malloc(sizeof(TPrvek));
            //clovek->parent2 = (TPrvek *) malloc(sizeof(TPrvek));I was desperate, this is wrong I think
        
            clovek->parent1 = db->TField[id1];
            clovek->parent2 = db->TField[id2]; 
        
            db->TField[id] = clovek;
//returns 1 if success
    }
```

and in the main I have simple asserts to check functionality like :

```
int main(int argc,
         char *argv[]) {
    DATABASE a;     
    init(&a);
    assert (addPerson(&a, 1, "John", 0, 0) == 1);
    assert (addPerson(&a, 2, "Caroline", 0, 0) == 1);
...}
```

Any ideas?
I'm pretty new to c and memory allocating in general, so I would be glad for every bit of help :)

Comment: Did you mean to use `newDb->size` rather than `db->size`? Can you provide a [mcve] so we can see how you're calling this? `clovek->parent1 = (TPrvek *) malloc(sizeof(TPrvek));` followed by `clovek->parent1 = db->TField[id1];` is a memory leak. Same with `parent2`.

Comment: The `*db = *newDb` is suspicious, but not necessarily wrong in itself.  Much depends on how this function is called and on what happens afterward.

Comment: Do note, however, that the `init()` function given leaks memory even if `*db = *newDb` is right.

Comment: yeah for sure thanks, I'll edit the original post. I'm trying to create database of presons each having father and mother (person1,person2) so I'm imagining it like a sort of hashTable with links to related persons. PS. you were right about the newDb!!! I'm really angry at myself but the code still has some other issues

Comment: There is way too much missing to tell what you are doing wrong except for the obvious things mentioned above. How do you call `init`, what is `name`?

Comment: I edited my original post, hope it's more reasonable now

Comment: What purpose does `newDB` serve? You already have `db`, right?

Comment: It would be best to create a [mcve]. What's missing is a `main` function showing how you call the `init` function and what `*db = *newDb;` is doing behind the scenes since we're not sure what was passed in. Worth noting that `*db = *newDb;` also leaks all of the memory, and any data, ever allocated or assigned to the original `db`. It would make more sense to me if `init` returned `DATABASE *` and was instead called something like `create`.

Comment: well I firstly returned newDB in init, but than I made some changes and now I have one instance of DATABASE in main (a in snipet) and change its vaule. I was just lazy to rewrite it in to work in db (it should be the same if im instancing new struct and than assert its value to it after i hope?)- that is the reason why newDb->size fluke happened in the first place

Comment: I believe it is aminimal reproducible sample, all I'm trying to do is to make the initial structure- thats why i have the asserts to check if it went ok, every other functionality should be more on top?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be able to be compiled (i.e. all headers and functions needed), not just some number of code snippets.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);` this does not what you think. `name` is a pointer, not an array. You want `strlen(name)+1`

Comment: My bad, I'll put them together. :)

Comment: As an aside, you don't need any of those casts.  It's simply `myPointerVariable = malloc(sizeof(myObjectType));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem (at least one I see straight away):

```
clovek->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);
```

Type of `name` is `char *`, and `sizeof(char *)` is size of pointer - always 8.
What you need instead is the length of string, i.e:

```
clovek->name = (char *) malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
```

Comment: The casting is not required.  C implicitly makes those casts already.

Comment: No need to limit to 64 bit systems. The code is also wrong for other pointer sizes.

Comment: Thanks, it was combination of this error and other little flukes commented above, thanks again guys